# jQuery Datatables Print Button - Columns not respecting print view bounds

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I have a table with 18 columns but when I try to print, table go past the bounds of the page view. Table is not adjusting right to the page limit.

https://s31.postimg.org/e2j2ptla3/IMAGE1.jpg

The weirdest thing is, if the document has more than two pages, the columns break perfectly and all columns are visible.

https://s32.postimg.org/e87am92s5/IMAGE2.jpg

How can I solve this problem?

This is the code I'm using for printing:

```
{
extend: 'print',
customize: function (win) {
$(win.document.body).find('table')
.addClass('compact')
.css('font-size', '6pt');

    },
    text: 'Click here to print',
    autoPrint: true,
    message: "Report 1",
    exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible'
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated.